# Why Underscores Theme Comment Form Reversed?

Tags: themes

Here is what I'm talking about

[image]

It's plain unmodified underscores theme, why is the comment form reversed starting from "comment" box first? I checked the functions files there aren't any codes that change the comment_form output.

- I'm running on WP 4.4.2
- No plugin activated
- Underscores theme freshly generated from underscores.me

is there a work around to quickly switch it back without re-creating the comment_form()? is this a feature? or did I miss something?

***Edit***

it turns out to be WP 4.4 feature [Changes to fields output by comment_form in WordPress 4.4](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/09/25/changes-to-fields-output-by-comment_form-in-wordpress-4-4/)

is there a fast work around to switch the form back to old one without creating comment-forms template or hooking? maybe additional arguments when calling comment_form?

Comment: curious to know what could be a reason to want the old behaviour? Anyway why is there a difference for you between additional argument and a hook?

Comment: Without hooking? Why would one avoid it since it's the most viable way to alter things.

Comment: Actually I'm looking for a way to like for example comment_form( array( 'old_style' => true ) ); because I hate customizing too much my theme since the more I customize it the more I need ro maintain compatibility and this feature just pop out after I updated the WP version.